# mysqldump.exe and mysql.exe access in C#

Tags: c#, .net, cmd, mysql

I'm writing an application which starts through command prompt `mysql.exe` and `mysqldump.exe`.
The idea is to make a backup and then upload it to mysql with different database name.
The problem is that I didn't think what would happen if these `mysql.exe` and `mysqldump.exe` are not registered in the cmd and you have to type the path to them manually.
And my application breaks.
So I'm wondering is there any automatic way to find the path to these two files to run them correctly.
The other solution that comes to my mind is to let the user browse his files and select these executables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manage this path you can use an environment variable and get it from your application.

```
string sPath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MYSQL_DIR");
```

Other solution is copy both executables to your application path and access them with a relative path.

```
string sPath = "./";
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I will try the first solution. I have thought about your second suggestion, but what if mysql versions are different?

Comment: This is the problem of the second option. If you upgrades your server version, you have to upgrade these executables too. Because the dump files can be incompatibles, but with the first option, you can have the same problem, but in another folder.

Comment: Hmmmm... `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MYSQL_DIR")` returns empty string. Am I missing something? :(

Comment: This environment variable can be created in the mysql installation. If you doesn't it, you can create it from "Start" -> Right Click in "Computer" -> "System Properties" -> "Environment Variables". And set the path to your mysql installation Path.